# How to build a basic embedded linux on a Qualcomm router?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded, arm, router

Not knowing the first thing on how to build a minimal linux system on an embedded device, I'd like to get some pointers in the right direction.

**Generally speaking**, I'd like to know what are the basic requirements, pieces and steps to get a an ultra minimalistic *nix shell to run on an embedded processor, not already containing any accessible OS.

**More specifically**, I have a Qualcomm `MDM9200` based router, that contain an embedded WebUI (probably `mini_httpd`), but is not running anything else, that can be accessed or used to change the WebUI. Also, this device is not based on a linux at all. So, I'd like to understand how I could run a simple linux like-shell (BusyBox?) on such a device?

Answer (score 1):

You need to cross-compile a whole system for the target architecture.
So, first you need to know if Linux is supported by the MDM9200 arch.

If answer is yes, the you need a cross-compilator for the target. Then you need to build a bootloader, a kernel and a minimalistic shell (busybox).

In order to achieve this, you can use tools like buildroot (or do it all by hand, but I recommend buildroot if it supports your target).

If you're interrested by embedded linux world, I suggest you to begin with well supported and documented cards, like Rapsberry Pi or many others ARM based SoC. It's not expensive and you can learn the basics, cross-compilation, uboot, busybox, etc..

Comment: Ok, so I have been looking around. It seem that this embedded processor is running on a Hexagon core. So I suppose I'd have to use those tools. So far I guess:
Linux Supported? Gobi/Linux-MSM? [ ],
Cross-compiler: Hexagon         [x],
Build Bootloader: Buildroot?      [ ],
Build Kernel:   <not sure>      [ ],
Build BusyBox:   [x], where x = I probably know how to do it... (I will hold off marking this as the preferred answer, until I can get some more pointers, by others.)